# Hiding selected features in ArcGIS for Desktop using ArcPy or ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, data-driven-pages

I'm using data driven pages to create a series of maps of point features.

Some of my features overlap spatially and I only want to show some of them on each map.

Once I select the features which I want to show, is there any way that I can hide the rest using ArcPy or ModelBuilder?

My whole setup is automatic, I don't want to do this manually!

Comment: Have a read of the data driven pages documentation, I believe there is something in there about this. You have to have the same value in a field as your page number I vaguely recall but there was special characters in the Definition Query to accomplish what you're after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing sounds like [Page Definition Queries](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s90000003p000000):

> Page Definition Queries allow you to specify which features of a layer
>   draw based on an SQL query. Though similar to other definition
>   queries, Page Definition Queries differ in that they only work with
>   Data Driven Pages and are dynamic.

If this is not what you are after then I recommend revising your question to provide more details because a more complex requirement will almost certainly need a mix of ArcPy and Data Driven Pages.

Comment: That's it PolyGeo, it basically comes down to having the same definition query or value in the very least for both layers. It was like that in DSMapBook which was the precursor to Data Driven Pages.