# How to display features one by one in Map Book?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages, map-book

I'm using "Data Driven Pages" Tool to create a map book in ArcMap. I want to display buffer circles **one by one** in each page, but the "Data Driven Pages" Tool displays all features around it.

How can I display one buffer circle without others in one page?

Can ArcMap do that? Or I need to learn ArcPy?

What I get:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this I would recommend that you investigate [Page Definition Queries](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s90000003p000000) which do not require the use of ArcPy.

You will find a few previous questions that involve them on this site like [Hiding selected features in ArcGIS for Desktop using ArcPy or ModelBuilder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110079/hiding-selected-features-in-arcgis-for-desktop-using-arcpy-or-modelbuilder)

Comment: PolyGeo nailed it - page definition queries are what you want.

Comment: I typically turn off the layer that defines my DDP and make a copy of it that will show the symbology that I want.  I use Page Definition Queries to only show the one that matches (or doesn't match) the page definition.

Comment: @Fezter Feel free to edit my Answer with this info (or more detailed steps if you are keen)